# Animated short about fat man eating everything in sight, including Earth

Tags: story-identification, cartoon

I'm looking for the name of an animated short seen on HBO or Showtime in the early 1980s. My parents had it recorded on VHS, and it may have been part of a larger film. The animation style was similar to  "Heavy Metal" (1980) but it wasn't part of that film. Although seen on American TV, there is no guarantee that the short was American in origin - I don't recall any dialogue throughout it. The entire thing was very short, less than 15 minutes if I remember it right.

In the short, a fat man in a white suit sits down to eat at a fancy restaurant. Think "Mr. Creosote" from Monty Python's The Meaning of Life, but animated. The man consumes everything brought to him much like Creosote does, but instead of puking or exploding he grows in size. Eventually he's eating trees, people, buildings, etc. As he continues to grow, he eventually consumes the entire planet and even the sun.

It's one of those things where I think of it from time to time, but can never remember the name of it and it always bugs me.

Comment: [_Hunger (1974)_](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vwU3UARE6yc) fits some points. Man in white suit eating all he can in restaurant, for instance.  But no eating of buildings and it ends differently.

Comment: *Hunger* (*La faim*) is the one I was thinking of too, but the ending is *very* different.  I did find [this comic though](https://www.antarcticajournal.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/Cartoon-A-Consumer.jpg).

Comment: Just checked Hunger, but that's not it. This one had an art style like the Heavy Metal movie in 1980 iirc.

Comment: I don't suppose it is Eat, by Bill Plympton?  https://vimeo.com/82140506

Comment: @CaptainSkyfish - nope, that's not it.

Comment: Katamari Damacy... Dah dah dah day dur dah dah